# Using HODL invoices as escrow services, nostr integration?

Tags: lightning-network, payment, escrow, invoices

With the growth of the nostr network, it's easy to imagine a whole new family of apps being created that could work in a decentralized manner (Marketplaces, AirBnB, Uber). But for these apps which require a type of deposit, an escrow system would be needed.
And just like relay addresses don't have to be hardcoded into Nostr apps, it should be possible to not have to hard-code trusted escrow services into apps, such that different implementations can discover mutual trusted escrow nodes in a real-time fashion.
I could imagine that a NIP could be created describing how escrow nodes could broadcast their services, such that two different marketplace apps being used by buyer/seller could dynamically discover available escrow nodes to facilitate the deposit payment. If we don't want to resort to base-chain multi-sig, or require wallets to add support for obscure side-chains, it seems that HODL invoices on the lightning network could achieve this in a non-custodial way, either forwarding the payment on success, or reversing the payment if the trade is disputed by the buyer.

I know that there are technical limitations to HODL invoices, such as the fact that they cause payments to get stuck and that each channel can only have a certain number of open HTLCs, but I want to know if there's an issue that would make it literally impossible to achieve this. The problems are as follows:

1. Max payment timeout: HODL invoices are possible for 2 weeks and under, but is there a reason that they cannot be held for 6 months, if trying to pre-book a hotel room for example.
   If there isn't a technical reason for not being able to hold payments for arbitrary amount of time, why would it not be possible for channels to price themselves by how long they're willing to lock funds for a specific payment?
   It seems that the network for instant payments could stay functional, where nodes charge small fees to route payments that timeout after 1 day for example, but other channels offer to route payments with a 1+ month timeout, but charge sizeable fees for locking up liquidity for that long. Why would it not be possible to have part of the lightning network optimized and priced for instant payments, and other channels optimized for longer pending 'deposits' and the two working symbiotically without impeding the other's capabilities?
2. Max concurrent HTLCs. Sounds like escrow nodes could only hold 483 concurrent deposits at a time due to the max size of bitcoin transactions. But does that mean that with some simple automated node management, an escrow node could open more channels to multiply the number of concurrent HTLCs in total? Would eventual transition to PTLCs up the limit of inflight payments at all?
3. Lastly, and least importantly, when a buyer is requesting the long-lasting payment invoice from the seller, there needs to be a way to specify a longer expiry. Current lightning-address capability doesn't seem to support this, but possibly the endpoints currently used for zaps could be used with some relatively minor? adjustments.

All in all, is this a no-go? Not possible? How else can we enable non-custodial escrow on nostr without resorting to base-chain or side-chains?

Comment: Take a look at Robosats